# ASP.NET MVC 3 application with multi-tenancy in separate app domains?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mef, multi-tenant, applicationdomain

Has anyone have idea how to implement multitenancy in asp mvc 3 application with support for separate app domains and MEF?

In my application I would like to load assemblies for each tenant to different app domain. Types are resolved by MEF in proper app domain. Every request needs to be handled in proper tenant specific app domain.

Since this is quite tough problem I would appreciate any insights.

Comment: There are tons of stackoverflow questions about this - do a search before asking a question.

Comment: You are not able to let IIS treat them as different applications?

Comment: Isn't this a similar question to the previous one you raised [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347865/how-to-handle-asp-net-mvc-requests-in-different-app-domains-in-multi-tenant-arch)?

Comment: I've done lot's of search in stackoverflow for such questions but found no results. Of course there are lots of similar ones but not excatly addressing my problem. The thing is that I would like to avoid configuring IIS to treat tenants as different applications and create instead "tenant manager" for managing tenants from the application level. @reach4thalasers - could you point to such questions? maybe I've missed something?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, multi-tenancy is all about the process of having a single code-base for all the tenants [Pure form of multi-tenancy].

When you will have all the options for a tenant to customize with a single code base and in a single appdomain, where the isolation happens based on the tenant identifier, there is no requirement for a separate app domain / tenant.

This ensures that each user that gets in to the system will get the data / customization based on the tenant that he belongs to [identified at runtime].

Please explore this view point and post your updates on this approach.